# Html table cell value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

How to get the cell value from html table if I have the corresponding row and column nos of html table cell?

For e.g. if the row no is 1 and column no is 3, how to take the cell value?

I used like this, it didnt work:

```
var value=document.getElementById("tablename").rows[len].cells[colno].innerHTML;
```

I am trying to get the values of the particular column.

Comment: you can use `eq()` selector to get the desired cell

Comment: `$('table tr:first td:eq(2)').text()`

Comment: is it a jQuery question? why don't you use jQuery selectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table id="mytable" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Jquery**

```
var rowno=0;
var colno=0;


var output=$("#mytable tr:eq("+rowno+") td:eq("+colno+")").html();
```

Output is Jackson

> **eq** selector

Zero-based index of the element to match.

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vzahd06h/)

Comment: It gives only undefined

Comment: eq is zero based. So, if you want to request line nr 1, you should use eq(0) etc

Comment: @NirmalAnand please add your HTML code. For better understanding

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eq()` function:

---

Insert the line and cell numbers and get the result:

```js
var getVal = function(trNum, tdNum) {
  var a = trNum - 1;
  var b = tdNum - 1;     
  return $('#tbl').find('tr').eq(a).find('td').eq(b).text();
}

$('#getRes').on('click', function() {
   var r = $('#line').val();
   var c = $('#cell').val();
   if (r && r.length > 0 && c && c.length > 0) {        
      $('#text').html('Result: ' + getVal(r,c));
   } else {
      alert('Insert data!');
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1.1</td>
      <td>1.2</td>
      <td>1.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2.1</td>
      <td>2.2</td>
      <td>2.3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<label for="line">Line</label>
<input id="line" type="number" /><br />
<label for="cell">Cell</label>
<input id="cell" type="number" /><br />
<button id="getRes">Get result</button>
<p id="text"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is fine, remember the row and columns are 0 based:

```js
//row 1 col 3
var len   = 1 - 1;
var colno = 3 - 1;

var value = document.getElementById("tablename").rows[len].cells[colno].innerHTML;
alert(value);
```

```html
<table id="tablename">
    <tr><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is almost right. Just use parseInt or parseFloat on what you get from the table. Here is a https://jsfiddle.net/4Ly53eoq/

parseInt if integer, parseFloat if fractional:

```
value; /* is a string */
parseInt( value ); /* is an integer */
parseFloat( value ); /* is a float */
```